# implement custom attribute renderer

Tags: jsf, custom-attributes, jsf-1.2, myfaces, tomahawk

Is possible develope custom implementation for input element attribute? For example if I specify in jsf page in input element: "required" (html5 attribute) in client HTML there isn't it and browser don't help me in validation. Is possible to declare render class with my method that traslate from jsf page to html attribute to send to client?

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible develope custom implementation for input element attribute?

I would think so (tomahawk by itself already is one)

> Is possible to declare render class with my method that traslate from jsf page to html attribute to send to client?

Yes

But you better switch to a more modetn jsf version and component suite